# Pygame Asteroid spawning issues

Tags: pygame

The code is supposed to spawn a temporary rock sprite after any sprite in the rocks list collides with the bullet sprite. Currently, the temporary rocks does not spawn. When I run the program to print the length of the list of rocks, the number increases if I shoot an asteroid, but a new one does not spawn.

```
class Rock(gameEngine.SuperSprite):

    def __init__(self, scene):
        gameEngine.SuperSprite.__init__(self, scene)

        self.setImage("rock.gif")
        self.reset()
    def checkEvents(self):
        self.rotateBy(self.rotSpeed)

    def reset(self):
        """ change attributes randomly """

        self.hitOnce = False
        #set random position
        x = random.randint(0, self.screen.get_width())
        y = random.randint(0, self.screen.get_height())
        self.setPosition((x, y))

        #set random size
        scale = random.randint(20, 40)
        self.scale = scale
        self.setImage("rock.gif")
        self.imageMaster = \
            pygame.transform.scale(self.imageMaster, (scale, scale))

        self.speed = random.randint(1,6)
        self.angle = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.setSpeed(self.speed)
        self.setAngle(self.angle)
        self.rotSpeed = random.randint(-5, 5)       


class Game(gameEngine.Scene, gameEngine.SuperSprite):

    def __init__(self):

        gameEngine.Scene.__init__(self)
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullet = Bullet(self)

        self.rocks = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.rocks.append(Rock(self))

        self.score = -50
        self.lives = 11

        self.lblInfo = gameEngine.Label()
        self.lblInfo.center = (175, 20)
        self.lblInfo.size = (350, 30)

        self.rockGroup = self.makeSpriteGroup(self.rocks)
        self.addGroup(self.rockGroup)
        self.sprites = [self.bullet, self.ship, self.lblInfo]
        self.setCaption("asteroids")

    def update(self):
        rockHitShip = self.ship.collidesGroup(self.rocks)
        if rockHitShip:
            rockHitShip.reset()
            self.lives -= 1

        rockHitBullet = self.bullet.collidesGroup(self.rocks)
        if rockHitBullet:
            if rockHitBullet.scale >= 20:
                rockHitBullet.setSpeed(rockHitBullet.speed * -1) #inverts the direction
                rockHitBullet.imageMaster = \
                    pygame.transform.scale(rockHitBullet.imageMaster, (rockHitBullet.scale/2, rockHitBullet.scale/2))

                self.tempRock = Rock(self)
                self.tempRock.rect.center = rockHitBullet.rect.center
                self.tempRock.dir = (rockHitBullet.dir - 90)
                self.rocks.append(self.tempRock)

            else:
                rockHitBullet.reset()

            self.bullet.reset()
            self.score += 50
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code on SO.

Comment: do you get error message when you run it ? show **full** message (Traceback) in question.

Comment: old method: use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. This way you can find the problem. (or learn how to use debuger)

Comment: There are no errors. It would seem that all the code is executed, but the new sprite does not spawn

Comment: maybe code is not executed - use `print()` to check it.

Comment: or maybe you have to add new rock to `Group()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lies here:

```
self.tempRock = Rock(self)
self.tempRock.rect.center = rockHitBullet.rect.center
self.tempRock.dir = (rockHitBullet.dir - 90)
self.rocks.append(self.tempRock)
```

You are creating a new rock, setting position and direction. Then you add it to your rocks list. So you will see the number of rocks increasing but you won't see it on the screen, since you are probably using the rockGroup() to draw your sprites. You take care of that in **init** but not in the update method.
Try adding the tempRock to the rockGroup(), and that should do the trick.

Comment: `self.rockGroup.add(self.tempRock)`

Comment: @Sean Yes, that would be the way to do it.